# How to make a cursor more efficient

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using a cursor to get incremental data on daily basis. Should cursor be useful or it will be faster by a merge clause in Oracle.

Comment: Why is this tagged for MySQL?  Are you using both MySQL and Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you can do something in SQL rather than PL/SQL, the SQL approach is going to be faster.  Row-by-row processing in PL/SQL, which is what I'm guessing your cursor-based approach is doing, will very, very rarely be as efficient as a single SQL statement.

As with anything, though, you'd need to test in your environment with your data to be sure.

Comment: well i am using pl/sql. .. i am using a cursor in a procedure and have to execute this procedure on a daily basis

Comment: It sounds like you are asking whether it would be better to loop over rows in a cursor (PL/SQL row-by-row processing) or to do a single `MERGE` (a single set-based SQL operation).  Set-based SQL will outperform row-by-row PL/SQL in the overwhelming majority of cases.